# CakePHP How to retrieve all Categories with Their Respective Articles and Display in Articles::Index

Tags: cakephp

I would like to retrieve a list of all categories with their corresponding posts (limit 10) and display it in the Index action/view of my Articles Controller. I already have the Articles and Categories controllers already setup.

I would like to have something similar to what [CNN.com](http://www.cnn.com) has at the bottom of its page.

What is the best approach?
Could you provide some code examples?

Thanks alot,

Andre S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is how I was able to solve this. If anyone has a best approach, please let me know. Thanks!**

This is my Index.ctp View file for Articles

```
<div id="bottom_section" class="article_bottom_section">
<?php
    foreach ($categories as $category){
?>
<div>
    <div>
        <?php echo $category['Category']['title'];?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
            echo $this->element(
                'category_relatedarticles',
            array(
            'categoryID' => $category['Category']['id']
            )
        );
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

Then is my index action in my Articles Controller

```
  $categories = $this->Article->Category->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Category.id',
                    'Category.title'
                ),
                'order' => 'Category.id DESC',
                'recursive' => 1
            )
        );

    $this->set('categories');
```

This is the element I am using to retrieve the corresponding articles

```
<div>
    <?php
    $RelatedArticles = $this->requestAction('/categories/getRelatedArticles/'.$categoryID);
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($RelatedArticles as $RelatedArticle){
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $RelatedArticle['Article']['title']; ?>
        </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the getRelatedArticles function in my Categories Controller

```
function getRelatedArticles($id = null){    

        $RelatedArticles = $this->Category->Article->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Article.title',
                    'Article.id'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Article.category_id =' => $id,
                ),
                'limit' => 6,
                'order' => 'Article.id DESC'            
            )
        );
        if (!empty($this->params['requested'])) {
            return $RelatedArticles;
        }else{
            $this->set('RelatedArticles');
        }
    }
```

And it works pretty nice... If anyone know a better and quicker way, please let me know.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a (cached) element and a request action; as it's unlikely the categories would change that much.

```
// views/elements/categories.ctp 
$categories= $this->requestAction('/categories/get_categories');
echo '<ul>';
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li>' . $category['Category']['name'] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';


// in your layout
echo $this->element('categories', array('cache' => '+1 hour'));
```

The above example would need tweaking; but you should get the idea. You can access any data you like using a request action; but it can cause poor performance - so caching is advisable.

See [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/991/requestAction) for more information.

Comment: Well, what I really wanted to do was retrieve Category 1 with 10 of its latest Articles, Category 2 with 10 of its latest articles and so on. Your answer just retrieve Categories, which I was already able to do. I just wanted best approach. See my answer to this question... I am not sure if that is the best approach, but that is how I did it.